# Absolute convergence of a complex sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove the following statement:

> The sequence $\{\vert c_{n} \vert \}$ of absolute values (or modulus of $c_n$’s) of a convergent sequence
> is convergent and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \vert c_n \vert = \vert \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n \vert$.

Here $c_n$'s are complex numbers.

The statement is intuitive but I'm facing trouble in writing a proper proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L = \lim c_n$. We need to prove that $\lim |c_n| = |L|$, i.e.

$$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists N \in \mathbb N)(n\ge N \implies \left||c_n| - |L|\right| < \epsilon)$$

By the [reverse-triangle-inequality](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ealfeld/math/equations/proof.html), $||c_n| - |L|| \le |c_n - L|$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate further?